# How to get html file to pdf file?

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.6

Here I am using html file to convert pdf file .It converts pdf file but html designs are not appears in converted pdf file.

```
import pdfkit
filename = "testfile.html"
with open(filename, "w") as file:
        file.write(message)
pdfkit.from_file(filename, 'my_testpdf.pdf')
```

Here It converts pdf file but html designs are not present in pdf file so any one help me to solve this

Answer (score 0):

You could use tools like [Fpdf](https://pypi.org/project/fpdf/)
 or [pypdf2](https://pypi.org/project/PyPDF2/)
 to write text html files
And Read docs on [write_html](https://pyfpdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/write_html/index.html) for more details